How to export/convert Google Doc into PDF with Google Apps Script
I need to fill out a PDF form with adjustable fields from from data from a Google Sheets file. I made a script currently (current script below) that is able to create a Google Doc with the fields filled in from Google sheets. Now I need to then convert the newly created Google Doc into a PDF. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!!
For context, basically what I need to do is to be able to create a bunch of PDFs similar to the attached picture where all I have to do is load in the data into a Google sheet and then populate that data nicely onto a Googledoc/PDF so if there's a much simpler way than what I am already doing, I am also open to new suggestions.(https://i.sstatic.net/H3CpkfPO.png)
enter image description here
Here is the Script I current have:
function onOpen() {
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  const menu = ui.createMenu('AutoFill Docs');
  menu.addItem('Create New Docs', 'createNewGoogleDocs')
  menu.addToUi();

}

function createNewGoogleDocs() {
  //This value should be the id of your document template that we created in the last step
  const googleDocTemplate = DriveApp.getFileById('19Yy2kyLKnvXYPJcOTxmv5GQ46JmpE1JHZSYkcfw1Z9s');
  
  //This value should be the id of the folder where you want your completed documents stored
  const destinationFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('1mWUtqLaaSpPbxIQdn0aARSnnRUH1DpQ6')
  //Here we store the sheet as a variable
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp
    .getActiveSpreadsheet()
    .getSheetByName('Data')
  
  //Now we get all of the values as a 2D array
  const rows = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  
  //Start processing each spreadsheet row
  rows.forEach(function(row, index){
    //Here we check if this row is the headers, if so we skip it
    if (index === 0) return;
    //Here we check if a document has already been generated by looking at 'Document Link', if so we skip it
    if (row[5]) return;
    //Using the row data in a template literal, we make a copy of our template document in our destinationFolder
    const copy = googleDocTemplate.makeCopy(`${row[1]}, ${row[0]} Employee Details` , destinationFolder)
    //Once we have the copy, we then open it using the DocumentApp
    const doc = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getId())
    //All of the content lives in the body, so we get that for editing
    const body = doc.getBody();
    //In this line we do some friendly date formatting, that may or may not work for you locale
    const friendlyDate = new Date(row[3]).toLocaleDateString();
    
    //In these lines, we replace our replacement tokens with values from our spreadsheet row
    body.replaceText('{{Name of Investment}}', row[0]);
    body.replaceText('{{Call #}}', row[1]);
    body.replaceText('{{Investor Name}}', row[2]);
    body.replaceText('{{Due Date}}', friendlyDate);
    body.replaceText('{{Current Call}}', row[4]);
    body.replaceText('{{Agreement Type}}', row[6]);
    body.replaceText('{{Total Commitment}}', row[7]);
    body.replaceText('{{Total Previous Called}}', row[8]);
    body.replaceText('{{Remaining Uncalled}}', row[9]);
    body.replaceText('{{Bank Name}}', row[10]);
    body.replaceText('{{Bank Account Name}}', row[11]);
    body.replaceText('{{Routing #}}', row[12]);
    body.replaceText('{{Bank Account #}}', row[13]);
 
    //We make our changes permanent by saving and closing the document
    doc.saveAndClose();
    //Store the url of our new document in a variable
    const url = doc.getUrl();
    //Write that value back to the 'Document Link' column in the spreadsheet. 
    sheet.getRange(index + 1, 6).setValue(url)
    
  })
  
}




Convert Google Doc into a PDF file
The code below converts a Google Document into a PDF file based on googleDocTemplate.
Here is the full code with your File ID and Folder ID:
 function onOpen() {
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  const menu = ui.createMenu('AutoFill Docs');
  menu.addItem('Create New Docs', 'createNewGoogleDocs')
  menu.addToUi();

}

function createNewGoogleDocs() {
  const googleDocTemplate = DriveApp.getFileById('19Yy2kyLKnvXYPJcOTxmv5GQ46JmpE1JHZSYkcfw1Z9s');
  const destinationFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('1mWUtqLaaSpPbxIQdn0aARSnnRUH1DpQ6');
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Data');
  const rows = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  rows.forEach(function (row, index) {
    if (index === 0) return;
    if (row[5]) return;
    const copy = googleDocTemplate.makeCopy(`${row[1]}, ${row[0]} Employee Details`, destinationFolder)
    const doc = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getId())
    const body = doc.getBody();
    const friendlyDate = new Date(row[3]).toLocaleDateString();

    body.replaceText('{{Name of Investment}}', row[0]);
    body.replaceText('{{Call #}}', row[1]);
    body.replaceText('{{Investor Name}}', row[2]);
    body.replaceText('{{Due Date}}', friendlyDate);
    body.replaceText('{{Current Call}}', row[4]);
    body.replaceText('{{Agreement Type}}', row[6]);
    body.replaceText('{{Total Commitment}}', row[7]);
    body.replaceText('{{Total Previous Called}}', row[8]);
    body.replaceText('{{Remaining Uncalled}}', row[9]);
    body.replaceText('{{Bank Name}}', row[10]);
    body.replaceText('{{Bank Account Name}}', row[11]);
    body.replaceText('{{Routing #}}', row[12]);
    body.replaceText('{{Bank Account #}}', row[13]);

    doc.saveAndClose();
    const pdf = DriveApp.getFileById(copy.getId()).getAs('application/pdf');
    const file = destinationFolder.createFile(pdf).setName(`${row[1]}, ${row[0]} Employee Details.pdf`);
    const url = file.getUrl();
    copy.setTrashed(true);
    sheet.getRange(index + 1, 6).setValue(url);
  })
}


Key Changes:
const url = doc.getUrl();
sheet.getRange(index + 1, 6).setValue(url)

to
const pdf = DriveApp.getFileById(copy.getId()).getAs('application/pdf');
const file = destinationFolder.createFile(pdf).setName(`${row[1]}, ${row[0]} Employee Details.pdf`);
const url = file.getUrl();
copy.setTrashed(true);
sheet.getRange(index + 1, 6).setValue(url);

Instead of pasting it as a generated Google Document, this pastes the converted document to PDF in Column F.

Output


Reference

Class DriveApp


If this resolves your issue, please click the accept button (checkmark icon) on the left. This helps others in the community with similar questions find solutions. If you don't see the accept button, feel free to let me know.
